# Microsoft SQL Server database / Visual Studio C# : date handling

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure out what would be the quickest and most convenient way to grab dates from the database and parse/cast them correctly into my DAL (DataAccessLayer) methods.

The columns inside my database are of datatype `date`.

Specifically I have this `Order` class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }  
public DateTime ConfirmedDeliveryDate { get; set; }  
public DateTime ShippingDate { get; set; }
public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
public List<Product> ListOfProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
```

And then of course I have a DAL method for, let's say, getting a list of orders from the database.

```
List<Order> GetAll()
{
  ... ... ...
  ... ... ...
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

  while(rdr.Read())
  {
    int orderId = (int)rdr["id"];
    DateTime orderDate = ???                 // HOW TO IMPLEMENT?
    DateTime? confirmedDeliveryDate = ???    // HOW TO IMPLEMENT?
    DateTime? shippingDate = ???             // HOW TO IMPLEMENT?
    ... ...
    ... ...

  }
  ... ... ...
}
```

NOTE: On my web I will only need `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` from the above mentioned dates. Not sure if that helps you, probably not but just wanted to say.

Comment: The quickest way is to use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) or a similar micro-ORM.

Comment: Your class doesn't have any nullable DateTime types, so either your read routing or class is incorrect. A date field should map to a DateTime instance, where everything in the time section would be zeros.

Comment: @insane_developer I can add those question marks in the class so they're nullable. Or just remove them from my DAL GetAll() method. But apart from that, im not sure how would i grab a **date** type from Database and parse it to VS C# DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `date` column in `sql` maps to a `DateTime` in `c#`. There is no need to do any special parsing. Assuming you're using a `SqlDataReader`, just use [`SqlDataReader.GetDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetDateTime_System_Int32_), or if you don't know the column ordinal use the [indexer and pass it the column name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_Item_System_String_) then cast the result to a `DateTime` just like you're doing with the `"id"` column.

```
DateTime orderedDate = (DateTime)rdr["orderedDate"];
// or
DateTime orderdDate = rdr.GetDateTime(/*column ordinal*/)
```

If the `date` columns in the database are nullable, then you need to account for that in your code by making the `DateTime` objects nullable (`DateTime?`) and checking for null when reading the results from the `SqlDataReader`.

```
List<Order> GetAll()
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        int orderId = (int)rdr["id"];
        DateTime? orderedDate = null;
        if (rdr["orderedDate"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            orderedDate = (DateTime)rdr["orderedDate"];
        }
    }
}
```

You could put this into an extension method on `SqlDataReader` if you wanted...

```
public static class SqlDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this SqlDataReader rdr, string columnName)
    {
        if (rdr[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            return (DateTime)rdr[columnName];
        }
        return null;
    }
}

List<Order> GetAll()
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        int orderId = (int)rdr["id"];
        DateTime? orderedDate = rdr.GetNullableDateTime("ordredDate");
    }
}
```

If your view only needs to display the year, month, and day then you can do that in several ways. For example, [`DateTime.ToShortDateString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring) or [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_).